# iTextg(for android) wont render table and ignores font settings

Tags: android, itext

My question is two-fold.

Firstly, when i create a Paragraph object, add some text, and a custom Font object, the Font object is completely ignored and had no effect on the text.

Secondly, when i create a PdfTable, add a single row just to test, it doesnt get rendered at all.

By the way, 90% of this code comes from tutorials from [here](http://valokafor.com/android-itext-pdf-example/) and [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/create-table-pdf-java-and-itext.html), all which had positive feedback. Here is the complete code:

```
PdfPTable table;
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    Font bfBold12 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
    Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));

    Font bf12 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
    File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/pdfdemo");
    if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
        pdfFolder.mkdirs();
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Pdf Directory created");
    }

    //Create time stamp
    Date date = new Date() ;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

    myFile = new File(pdfFolder, "testPDF.pdf");

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

    //Step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

    //Step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

    //Step 3
    document.open();

    Paragraph top = new Paragraph("Quotation");
    top.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    top.setFont(titleFont);//completely ignored

    document.add(top);

    Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Text to the left");
    p.add(new Chunk(glue));
    p.add("Text to the right");

    document.add(p);

    //specify column widths
    float[] columnWidths = {1.5f, 6f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f};
    //create PDF table with the given widths
    table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    // set table width a percentage of the page width
    table.setWidthPercentage(90f);

    insertCell("Item No.", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
    insertCell("Description", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
    insertCell("Qty", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
    insertCell("Discount(%)", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
    insertCell("Unit Price", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
    insertCell("Line Total", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);

    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    document.add(table);

    document.close();

}


private void insertCell( String text, int align, int colspan, Font font){

    //create a new cell with the specified Text and Font
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text.trim(), font));
    //set the cell alignment
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
    //set the cell column span in case you want to merge two or more cells
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    //in case there is no text and you wan to create an empty row
    if(text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        cell.setMinimumHeight(10f);
    }

    //add the call to the table
    table.addCell(cell);      
}
```

**And this is the output:** [image: result]

Comment: What's wrong with the official documentation on http://developers.itextpdf.com ? Why do you prefer third party documentation? Please answer, because I'm the author of most of the official documentation and I want to know what I've been doing wrong the many hours, days, weeks and months I've been writing documentation.

Comment: My apologies sir, I was looking for an example specific to Android(iTextG), not just plain Java, and as for the other link, thats where i discovered your *brilliant* library. Only after implementing(and going to the official documentation for something else) did i realise how interchangeable the samples were(between iTextG and iText 5/7). It would be nice to find platform specific examples on your site though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Paragraph top = new Paragraph("Quotation");
top.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
top.setFont(titleFont);//completely ignored
```

This is completely ignored because you do not add text to the paragraph after setting the font. The font does not apply to existing content but to later added content (without font).

```
table.setHeaderRows(1);
```

As you add only cells for one row and declare one header row, the table only has headers but no content. Thus, it is empty and will not be drawn at all.